# How to deploy docker react app on clever-cloud

Tags: docker, deployment, dockerfile

I am new to both clever cloud and docker. I want to create an application running on docker with nginx and react to clever cloud. But, everytime I push to clever cloud, deployment failed
ERROR MESSAGE:

> Nothing listening on 0.0.0.0:8080 yet. If the deployment fails after this message, please update your configuration and redeploy.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    front:
        container_name: front
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - '.:/app'
            - '/app/node_modules'
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        labels:
            NAME: "App Front"
        networks:
            - app-network
        environment:
            - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
        expose:
          - 8080

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Content of the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn run build
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app works fine on Clever Cloud.

Your app should listen on 0.0.0.0:8080, you can set this with environment variables (HOST and PORT).

If you are deploying a Docker application that is not listening on 8080, you can use the CC_DOCKER_EXPOSED_HTTP_PORT environment variable to define the correct port.

NOTE: There are some issues with the latest version (3.4.1)

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

Several solutions are proposed to fix this :

```
Add stdin_open: true on your docker-compose command
Add an CI=true as an environment variable
Downgrade your react-scripts to 3.4.0
```